# File-transform-task in Azure DevOps release-pipeline not substituting variables

Tags: xml, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, variable-substitution

In my project, there is a Webservice.settings containing **3 variables**. ([Structure of Webservice.settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myNnV.png))
I intent to set these variables with my **release-pipeline (Azure DevOps)**. Therefore, I created a variable-group in DevOps, containig the variables and the values I want to set. ([Structure of variable-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIle6.png))
The variable-group was **linked to the pipeline** and its scope was set to "**release**".

To set the variables, the release-pipeline contains a **file-transform-task**. ([Structure of file-transform-task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptMlT.png)

After the pipeline has run, the **.exe.config** looks like this:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
      <setting name="UrlEndpoint" serializeAs="String">
        </value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginName" serializeAs="String">
        </value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginPasswort" serializeAs="String">
        </value>
      </setting>
    </MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
  </applicationSettings>
```

The variables haven't been set.

**My expectations** were, that the **.exe.config** should have looked something like this:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
      <setting name="UrlEndpoint" serializeAs="String">
        <value>NoUrlEndpointNameSet</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>NoLoginNameSet</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LoginPasswort" serializeAs="String">
        <value>NoLoginPasswortSet</value>
      </setting>
    </MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
  </applicationSettings>
```

What I've tried: I assumed, that I addressed the namespace inside the variable-group wrong. So inside the variable-group, I tried different options like:

- MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice.LoginName
- Properties.Webservice.LoginName
- etc.
  I checked the MS-documentation, but couldn't find anything matching my case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v1?view=azure-pipelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial-and-error, coffee and a mild headache, I found the problem and solved it.

I added some default-values to my Webservice.settings ([Added values via designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQVIW.png))

This lead to a slightly different structure in my .exe.config:

```
<MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
  <setting name="UrlEndpoint" serializeAs="String">
    <value>someValue</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LoginName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>defaultPlaceholderLoginName</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LoginPasswort" serializeAs="String">
    <value>defaultPlaceholderLoginPasswort</value>
  </setting>
</MyFancyProgram.App.Properties.Webservice>
```

The important part here is, that for each variable-value there is now an opening- and closing-tag.

```
<value>someValue</value>
```

Before, there was only a "two in one"-tag.

```
<value/>
```

It looks like the file-transform-task performs its variable substitution **only inside opening- and closing-value-tags** and not inside "two in one"-value-tags.

Appendum: A whitespace as default-value doesn't suffice to replace the "two in one"-value-tags with a opening- and closing-value-tag-pair.